# Proofs of converge of $\zeta(\sigma+it)$ don't seem to show divergence for $\sigma<1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta

It is well known that the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ over the complex domain converges for $\sigma>1$, where $s=\sigma+it$.

The most common proofs use the triangle inequality to show that that

$$\left|\sum\frac{1}{n^{s}}\right|\leq\sum\left|\frac{1}{n^{\sigma}}\frac{1}{n^{it}}\right|$$

and use $n^{it} = e^{it\ln(n)}$ to make clear $n^{it}$ has a magnitude of 1. This leaves us with

$$\left|\sum\frac{1}{n^{s}}\right|\leq\sum\frac{1}{n^{\sigma}}$$

We know from other methods (comparing sums to integrals, for example) that $\sum\frac{1}{n^{\sigma}}$ converges for $\sigma>1$.

Those proofs then conclude that the complex zeta function $\zeta(s)$ converges for $s>1$ because the magnitude of the sum is dominated by the real valued $\zeta(\sigma)$.

**Question**: The above logic seems to exclude showing that there is no $\sigma<1$ for which the complex $\zeta(s)$ converges.

What have I misunderstood?

As context, the integral test for real $\zeta(\sigma)$ for does test for both possibilities ([link](https://fromprimestoriemann.blogspot.com/2021/02/integral-comparison-tests.html)).

Comment: Do you know dirichlet series theory? Convergence at a point implies convergence to the right of it (uniform in angles) so divergence at real sigma $\le 1$ implies the series cannot converge to the left of $1$; on the line $\sigma=1$ one needs a special argument,  but it is not hard to show that the series oscillates there so is not convergent at any point

Comment: hi @Conrad I'm not familiar with Dirichlet series theory, I will google it. Recommendations welcome!